# Spring Boot App losing session data in chrome

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

Whenever I use google chrome to hit my application, almost any requests that I make are not hitting the rest service. However, I can login and hit the rest service, the problem is once I get to the home page, any requests after the initial login all fail. Instead it seems like the session is becoming invalidated. I checked some other stack overflow threads and saw this may have to do with a 302 error occurring when the browser is trying to load the favicon.ico. I can see in the network tab of my developer tools that this is infact getting a 302. I am unsure if this is the actual issue and or is there is another issue.

Comment: Are you getting 302 every time or just after the login? 302 means you are getting redirected to a new url, if there is any authentication error related to login you will get 401 or 403.

Comment: @user12047085 I am getting 302 every time on that. however that might not be the problem. for some reason it seems like the httpsession is becoming null after login. and this occurs sporadically. so sometimes the site works with no problems, others it will fail every call after the initial login

Comment: What's your security setup? It works well with other browsers?

Comment: @medTech the only other browser this has problem with is firefox. i also use redis so maybe that could be an issue?

Comment: Hard to say without having a look at your security config and session config. Is Spring Session enabled in your application. Because Spring will use the Tomcat provided Session per default. If you want to switch to redis you have to enable Spring Session and the redis configuration https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/